# Invalid type for the dependent variable in lm() in R programming

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

This is an R problem, not a statistics problem.

I am trying to perform multiple linear regression in R for a set of 20 independent variables and 1 dependent variable. The 20 independent variables are in one csv file and the 1 dependent variable is in another csv file. Each row in each file corresponds to one measurement a day.

I have managed to import the 20 independent variables using read.csv(...) into a (variable?) called "predictors". I then imported the dependent measurements, again using read.csv(...), into a (variable?) called "dependent".

However when I use lm(dependent~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+X7+X8+X9+X10+X11+X12+X13+X14+X15+X16+X17+X18+X19+X20)

(Note: X_1,...,X20 are the headers of the columns for the predictors in that csv file)

I get the error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = dependent ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 +  : 
>     invalid type (list) for variable 'dependent'

I cannot understand what is going wrong?

The predictors file looks something like (but up to X20)

[image]

and the dependent csv file looks like

[image]

Comment: Try to add the dependent variable as a column in the dataframe along with the independent variables.

Comment: from the look of your error, I would say that dependent is a list. It would be much better if you had a dataframe with 21 columns : your 20 Xs and the dependent variable. Then, running a regression would be quite easy. You could look at `cbind` to append 2 dataframes

Comment: Show us the data structures you use in R (after import). Data from excel is nice, but doesn't tell the whole story. For information on how to present data, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example (hint: `str()`).

Comment: @etienne I think that append the two dataframes sounds promising. However, would it affect the original csv files? I would prefer to not do so because of the risk of me making mistakes. Also the dependent file does not have a header, should I just fix this manually?

Comment: @Jurassic: it will not affect the files as it is done in R. Only the dataframes in R would be changed

Comment: What about the problem with the (missing) header in the dependent file? Im fairly new to R, so I might be asking stupid questions

Comment: @Jurassic: please post the content of `dput(head(dependent,20))`

Comment: @etienne structure(list(dependent = c(0.492953411, 0.043316894, 0.531063462, 
0.069835297, 0.745747788, 0.563491793, 0.361391002, 0.941001038, 
0.42188846, 0.701243033, 0.244971598, 0.715131866, 0.059934703, 
0.833232638, 0.931180818, 0.14137212, 0.120101559, 0.696456147, 
0.814202024, 0.402056469)), .Names = "dependent", row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @Jurassic: if the headers of the dataframe with 20 columns are just the names of the columns (they should be), `cbind(dependent, df)` should work fine. Otherwise, re-import df (that is, the 20 columns dataframe) by specifying `header=TRUE` in the `read.csv` command

Comment: @etienne All fixed. I think you deserve some points for cbind, post below and i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have some random data for df :

```
df<-replicate(5,rnorm(20))
names<-paste0('X',1:5)
colnames(df)<-names
```

dependent is already given in the comments, so we can use `cbind` to create one dataframe :

```
newDf<-cbind(dependent,df)

head(newDf)
#    dependent           X1         X2         X3           X4          X5
# 1 0.49295341 -1.728304515  0.9902622  0.6164557  0.904435464 -0.65801021
# 2 0.04331689  0.641830028  2.3829267  0.6165678  0.002691661  0.85520221
# 3 0.53106346 -1.529310531  0.6644159 -1.6921015 -1.176692158  1.15293623
# 4 0.06983530  0.001683688  0.2073812  0.3687421 -1.318220727  0.27627456
# 5 0.74574779  0.250247821 -2.2106331  0.9678592 -0.592997366  0.14410466
# 6 0.56349179  0.563867390  2.6917140  1.2765787  0.797380501 -0.07562508
```

We can then run the regression :

```
lm(dependent~.,newDf) # . selects all the other columns of newDf

# Call:
# lm(formula = dependent ~ ., data = newDf)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           X1           X2           X3           X4           X5  
#     0.50522     -0.09975     -0.03040      0.06431     -0.00398     -0.09596
```